# How to structure database and populate Calendar in CodeIgniter 2 project?

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar, codeigniter-2

I've searched SO and Google and can't quite find what I need.

I'm building a simple Event Calendar with CodeIgniter 2.  [As per the CodeIgniter documentation,](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/calendar.html) this is the basic code structure and it's working...

```
// $data[2] contains the data for day #2, etc.

$data[2] = '<a href="#">event title 1</a>';
$data[8] = '<a href="#">event title 2</a><br/><a href="#">event title 3</a>';
$data[13] = '<a href="#">event title</a>';
$data[24] = '<a href="#">event title</a>';

// {content} in template is where $data is inserted for each day

$prefs = array (
    // my calendar options
    'template'  => '
        {cal_cell_content}{day}<br/>{content}{/cal_cell_content}
        {cal_cell_content_today}<div class="highlight">{day}<br/>{content}</div>{/cal_cell_content_today}'
);

$this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);

$year   = ($year === FALSE ? date('Y') : $year);
$month  = ($month === FALSE ? date('m') : $month);

echo $this->calendar->generate($year, $month, $data);
```

---

Now comes how I've set up my database table...

- Each Event has a `title` field and that creates the `$slug`.  (`~/events/view/title-slug`)
- Each Event has a `date` field and the data format is `mm/dd/yyyy`

Now, I'm thinking about how I'd query the database for a particular month/year and extract the data to insert into each `$data[]` variable.

It seems like I'll need to do the following:

- create new columns in my database table for `month`, `day`, and `year`.
- take my `date` input data, after it's validated, and save it into `date` column.
- split apart my `date` input data, and save each piece into `month`, `day`, and `year` columns.

Then I would simply query my database for `year` & `month`, then loop through these results to construct my `$data[]` array for each `day`.

Is this the correct way I should be approaching this problem?  It seems very redundant to have a `date` column as well as `month`, `day`, and `year` columns.  Can it be done with only the `date` (`mm/dd/yyyy`) column?  Too simple?  Too complex?  I'd like to avoid giving the user more than one field for entering a date, and ultimately I'll have a jQuery date-picker to help ensure the proper data format.

I know this may seem like a simple problem, but I've failed to locate simple code examples online.  Most of the ones I've found are out of date (CI instead of CI2), too complex for what I'm doing, or use daily content items which have URI segments that already contain the date (`~/events/view/yyyy/mm/dd`).

---

**EDIT**:

This is how my Model is presently setup:

```
return $this->db->get_where('events', array('yyyy' => $year, 'mm' => $month))->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I changed my `date` column into the MySQL "date" format, `yyyy-mm-dd`, in order to take advantage of the [built-in MySQL date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

My original $query is as follows, where the `'yyyy'` and `'mm'` are my redundant "year" and "month" columns:

```
$this->db->get_where('events', array('yyyy' => $year, 'mm' => $month))->result_array();
```

I simply changed it into the following using the built-in MySQL date functions:

```
$this->db->get_where('events', array('YEAR(date)' => $year, 'MONTH(date)' => $month))->result_array();
```

This solved the question.  Now I no longer need to maintain the extra columns for "year" and "month".

---

Additionally, I can assign the "day" portion of the `date` column to a virtual column called `dd` by using the MySQL "alias" function:

```
$this->db->select('DAY(date) AS dd');
```

However, this would fail since it over-rides CI's default `select('*')`.  So you'll have to `select()` all the relevant columns first or it will give an error:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->select('DAY(date) AS dd');
```

And putting it all together in the Model:

```
// select all relevant columns
$this->db->select('*');

/* use MySQL date functions to creates virtual column called 'dd' containing
"day" portion of the real 'date' column. */
$this->db->select('DAY(date) AS dd'); 

/* use MySQL date functions to match $year and $month to "year" and "month"
portions of real 'date' column. */  
return $this->db->get_where('events', array('YEAR(date)' => $year, 'MONTH(date)' => $month))->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leave everything as-is and just structure your query to return the month and year as separate columns:

in SQL:

```
SELECT id, 
       title, 
       description, 
       MONTH(date_field) as event_month, 
       YEAR(date_field) as event_year 
FROM my_table
... etc ...
```

and in Active Record ([taken from here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/74206/#368777)):

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->select('title');
$this->db->select('description');
$this->db->select("MONTH(date_field) AS event_month");
$this->db->select("YEAR(date_field) AS event_year");
$query = $this->db->get('my_table');
$results = $query->result();
```

Comment: I'm not understanding how this works.  How does `MONTH(date)` know which part of my date string is the month?

Comment: Assuming you're using MySQL - `MONTH` is a core function that returns just the month from a `date` field:  [date-and-time-functions.html#function_month](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)  --  I'm also assuming you're using a fieldtype of `date` for your date field and not `varchar`

Comment: My `date` field contains the date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format and I guess I  had not set up my field type properly.

Comment: Yes, if it's not too late in the project, I'd suggest updating that field. Better to take advantage of native types. I believe the format for the `date` type is: yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: It's not too late and when I changed it, I lost all my dummy `date` data.  What about data entry?  I think 2012-02-29 is less intuitive for the user than 02/29/2012.  I'd rather not have to constantly manipulate this from database to display and back again... unless there is a function that handles that automatically.

Comment: If you're using jquery datepicker, that fixes that - but you can also format with `date('m-d-Y', $mydate);`

Comment: you can do the datepicker thing, the format thing or honestly just put a placeholder on the text input showing YYYY-MM-DD and people will fill it in right, then run form validation against it and tell them if it's wrong.

Comment: Can this be done using CodeIgniter's Active Record class?  How?

Comment: Yes, [take a look here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/74206/#368777) for an example - this uses `DATEFORMAT`, but would be the same idea for the `MONTH` and `YEAR` functions.

Comment: I converted my `date` field to `date` format in my MySQL table, but no matter what, I couldn't get `MONTH()` or `YEAR()` to work.  (kept getting various errors).   I just ended up keeping my `mm` and `yyyy` integer fields.  It made things very easy where I could just use Active Record to do this in one line:  `$this->db->get_where('events', array('yyyy' => $year, 'mm' => $month))->result_array()`.  I'll revisit this again later just to make sure.

Comment: +1 for putting me on the right path by pointing out the built-in MySQL date functions.  However, constructing the query itself did not require making the "alias" columns.  Thanks again!